# Android JSON Object

Tags: android, json, arrays

I have a JSON format like this

> {"response":{"status":true,"result":"user_exists"}}

Now i am trying to retrieve the Status value to do some logic

```
JSONObject jData = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray response = jData.getJSONArray("response");
```

But i am getting the following error

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"result":"user_exists","status":true}
>   at response of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to
>   JSONArray

how to retrieve an Object from inside and Object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to retreive the status attribut from a `JSONArray` but , you don't have any `JSONArray` in your Code , ( `JSONArray` is surrounded by `[]` , and `JSONObject` is surrounded by `{}` ) , 
So to retreive the status value , try this :

```
JSONObject jData = new JSONObject(data);
JSONObject response = jData.getJSONObject("response");

boolean status = response.getBoolean("status");
```

Answer (score 5):

`response` is a JSONObject, not a JSONArray. Array objects are surrounded by these `[]` brackets, objects are with the normal ones `{}`. *(See [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for more format information)*

Change

```
JSONArray response = jData.getJSONArray("response");
```

to

```
JSONObject response = jData.getJSONObject("response");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first navigate to the response object by

`JSONObject response = jData.getJSONObject("response")` instead of `JSONArray`, as response is a object.

Answer (score 1):

`response` isn't an array but an object. Use `getJSONObject` and `JSONObject` instead of `getJSONArray` and `JSONArray`.