# How to get & parse a JSON object in Android?

Tags: android, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I parse JSON from a Java HTTPResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845599/how-do-i-parse-json-from-a-java-httpresponse)
>   [How to parse json string in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091051/how-to-parse-json-string-in-android)

How can i parse this json string

```
{
"apiVersion": "2.1",
"data": {
    "id": "pHuoDqcIyqk",
    "uploaded": "2012-10-29T16:08:15.000Z",
    "updated": "2012-11-02T08:48:28.000Z",
    "uploader": "googlenexus",
    "category": "Tech",
    "title": "Nexus: Ask Me Anything",
    "description": "The Best of Google, now in 3 sizes. Introducing Nexus 4, Nexus 7 and Nexus 10. The new smartphone and tablets from Google. Shop now at play.google.com/nexus",
    "thumbnail": {
        "sqDefault": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/pHuoDqcIyqk/default.jpg",
        "hqDefault": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/pHuoDqcIyqk/hqdefault.jpg"
    },
    "player": {
        "default": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHuoDqcIyqk&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
        "mobile": "http://m.youtube.com/details?v=pHuoDqcIyqk"
    },
    "content": {
        "5": "http://www.youtube.com/v/pHuoDqcIyqk?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata",
        "1": "rtsp://v8.cache5.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmpyginDqh7pBMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
        "6": "rtsp://v7.cache4.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmpyginDqh7pBMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
    },
    "duration": 61,
    "aspectRatio": "widescreen",
    "rating": 4.8985643,
    "likeCount": "5227",
    "ratingCount": 5363,
    "viewCount": 1038854,
    "favoriteCount": 0,
    "commentCount": 1442,
    "accessControl": {
        "comment": "allowed",
        "commentVote": "allowed",
        "videoRespond": "moderated",
        "rate": "allowed",
        "embed": "allowed",
        "list": "allowed",
        "autoPlay": "allowed",
        "syndicate": "allowed"
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to make a call to the above URL & get a JSON object, then parse it to get the desired info as a string?

Comment: i dont have any idea of making webcalls , so waiting for solution.Pls help

Comment: there are many links for json parsing ........try yourself first...one of the link is http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: learn how to parse json string from this site http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I did homework for you: [Android - JSON Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+json+parsing)

Comment: please tell me way first to get desired json object , parsing is secondary thing but how to make call first to get json object?

Comment: I would request you to search Google and stackoverflow.com before posting the question. you would always found solution and sample code for generic problems.

Comment: wait i ll give you all code..

Answer (score 0):

Well too broad a question you are asking..

1) Do a [http get](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) request on the URL. (Or using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162260/how-to-work-with-an-image-using-url-in-android) method) and get the response String, which is JSON. Some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455831/http-get-request-in-android-2-3-3)

2) See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294062/android-json-object) answer to see how to parse JSON.

Answer (score 0):

simple simple....

```
String str = "" // your JSON string
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String apiVersion = json.getString("apiVersion");
 // continue as before for the rest of it...
```

Answer (score 0):

you Can try below method. you can pass URL and get the Response as **result** String. 
public static String result;

```
public static boolean connect(String url) {
        boolean flag = false;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
        Log.e("url", url);

        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        try {

            // https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/audio.search?uid=163398985&q=akoncount=100&access_token=2a4db0e223f0f5ab23f0f5ab5f23da5680223f023f1f5a3c696b018be9b17b9

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // Examine the response status
            Log.i("vkontake", response.getStatusLine().toString() + "\n"
                    + response);

            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release

            if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                Log.d("Jsomn Activity", "---- is --- " + instream);
                result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                Log.d("Jsomn Activity", "---- Result --- " + result);

                // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
                instream.close();

            } else {
                Log.d("Jsomn Activity", "---- is --- null ");
            }
            flag = true;
            net = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Jsomn Activity", "---- Catch --- " + e.toString());
            flag = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return flag;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One easy way is to define an object structure that matches your data and use http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ to fill it:

```
final URL url = new URL("http://yourURL.com");
final InputStream openStream = url.openStream();
final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(openStream);
final SearchResult searchResult = new Gson().fromJson(inputStreamReader, SearchResult.class);
```

If your searchResult class containts a field e.g. apiVersion, it will be filled with the data from JSON. Then you have a data field with the other fields inside etc. This is a very easy way to populate your data, but you will have to mirror the structure of the JSON stream in your object model.

Answer (score -1):

The [JSON.org site](http://json.org/) contains no less than 20 different java implementations of JSON parsers.